# Setting onSeekBarChangeListener causes null object exception

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm trying to update a textview with the value of a seekbar, and I'm having trouble setting an OnSeekBarChangeListener. I don't have any compile errors, but every time I try to run the app, I get a null pointer exception.

The error says:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference

I can't for the life of me figure out why, despite trawling through StackOverflow. Every similar problem, or tutorial on how to set an OnSeekBarChangeListener seems to suggest I do exactly what I've done. Help!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView time;
public SeekBar bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(listener);

}

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener listener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        time.setText((String.valueOf(progress/100) + ":" + String.valueOf(progress % 100)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};}
```

Comment: `bar` is null. Are you sure your resources, particularly `R.id.bar`, are set up properly?

Comment: Take a look at @prograde's answer. If you haven't set the content view yet, the calls to findViewById will fail. I think you will find that `time` is null, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try to set these lines

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

first in the onCreate-method, and after that, try to find the seekBar view with

```
bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
```

Please, let me know if it solves your problem!

The findViewById() method will try to find the view with the specified ID. But to do that, it has to know which layout file is used for the activity, so that it knows where to search. That's what you point out with the setContentView, and that's why it has to come first.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! That fixed it! And thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `onCreate` with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(listener);
}
```

You should call `setContentView()` before using `findViewById`!

Answer (score 0):

This error occur too when you call  an wrong  activity or when you call the correct activity and call another wrong activity that do not have the component you want, example

```
setContentView(R.layout.correct_activity_with_your_component);
some code....    setContentView(R.layout.wrong_activity_without_your_component_bar_activity_main);
bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
```

So one solution is write the line similar to
    setContentView(R.layout.correct_activity_with_your_component);
**before** your componenet and **verify** if there is not **another** command 
similar to

```
setContentView(R.layout.correct_activity_with_your_component);
```

before you call your component with:

```
bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
```