# Null object reference error on findViewById() even when invoked after setContentView()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an instance of a SeekBar using the `findViewById()` and attaching a listener to it.

The code looks like this:

```
SeekBar seek_bar = findViewById(R.id.audio_volume);
seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(listener);
```

And the listener:

```
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener listener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            log.d("YO HERE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    };
```

Followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301028/setting-onseekbarchangelistener-causes-null-object-exception), and invoked the `findViewById` inside the `onCreate` method after these two lines:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

But the problem persists. I am still getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference
```

And the app fails to open. How can I solve this issue? Also it would be very helpful if the process of debugging a null object reference error is shared.

Layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <ListPreference
   android:key="PREF_MIN_REC"
   android:title="@string/min_rec"
   android:summary="@string/min_rec_desc"
   android:entries="@array/min_rec_options"
   android:entryValues="@array/min_rec_values"
   android:dialogTitle="@string/min_rec"
   android:defaultValue="15"
  />
  <ListPreference
   android:key="PREF_AUDIO_SOURCE"
   android:title="@string/audio_source"
   android:summary="@string/audio_source_desc"
   android:entries="@array/audio_source_options"
   android:entryValues="@array/audio_source_values"
   android:dialogTitle="@string/audio_source"
   android:defaultValue="4"
  />
  <ListPreference
    android:key="PREF_AUDIO_FORMAT"
    android:title="@string/audio_format"
    android:summary="@string/audio_format_desc"
    android:entries="@array/audio_format_options"
    android:entryValues="@array/audio_format_values"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/audio_format"
    android:defaultValue="1"
  />
    <org.anasthase.androidseekbarpreference.SeekBarPreference
        android:id="@+id/volume"
        android:key="PREF_MIC_VOLUME"
        android:title="@string/mic_volume"
        android:summary="@string/mic_volume_desc"
        app:maxValue="100"
        app:minValue="1"
        app:stepValue="1"
        android:defaultValue="20"
        app:format="%.1f"
        app:displayDividerValue="5"/>

  <org.anasthase.androidseekbarpreference.SeekBarPreference
          android:id="@+id/audio_volume"
          android:key="PREF_AUDIO_VOLUME"
          android:title="@string/audio_volume"
          android:summary="@string/audio_volume_desc"
          app:maxValue="100"
          app:minValue="1"
          app:stepValue="1"
          android:defaultValue="20"
          app:format="%.1f"
          app:displayDividerValue="5"/>


  <EditTextPreference
    android:key="PREF_URL_SUBDOMAIN"
    android:title="@string/server_subdomain"
    android:summary="@string/server_subdomain_desc"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/server_subdomain"
    android:defaultValue=".telforce.biz"
  />
  <ListPreference
      android:key="PREF_UPLOAD_NETWORK"
      android:title="@string/upload_network"
      android:summary="@string/upload_network_desc"
      android:entries="@array/upload_network_options"
      android:entryValues="@array/upload_network_values"
      android:dialogTitle="@string/upload_network"
      android:defaultValue="1"
      />

  <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="save_term_enable_key"
    android:title="@string/save_term_check_title"
    android:summary="@string/save_term_check_summary"/>
  <EditTextPreference
    android:key="save_term_key"
    android:title="@string/save_term_title"
    android:summary="@string/save_term_summary"
    android:dependency="save_term_enable_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/save_term_default_value"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/save_term_dialog"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: post layout resource also.

Comment: Added layout @adnbsr

Comment: Tried adding this but got `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'org.anasthase.androidseekbarpreference.SeekBarPreference'`

Comment: can you post your whole layout?

Comment: you should check library's docs. It should be used in prefs layout.

Comment: do this way if its preference fragment:
`SeekBarPreference skp = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference(R.id.audio_volume);`

Comment: @Faisal updated with full layout. Tried adding `SeekBarPreference seek_bar = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference(R.id.audio_volume);` but isn't findPreference deprecated as of API level 16?

Comment: do this way if its preference fragment:
`SeekBarPreference skp = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("PREF_AUDIO_VOLUME");`

Comment: I don't think its deprecated. have a look at my gradle:
`android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.2.18"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }`

minimum sdk is 21 and I'm using it.

Comment: check my second comment. Instead of passing id, pass key and it'll find your preference.

Comment: @Faisal Thanks man! It's working alright now!

Comment: @Faisal Can you please add it as answer as well? Will be helpful for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this way if its preference fragment:

```
SeekBarPreference skp = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("PREF_AUDIO_VOLUME");
```

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your XML your audio_volume view belongs to class
org.anasthase.androidseekbarpreference.SeekBarPreference

In your Java code, it is SeekBar only, so if it is not crashing, I assume Seekbar extends SeekBarPreference.

Ignore the casting comments and responses since it's not needed since last year if you're using the latest versions of java, android sdk and target api.

The null pointer exception means the seekbar was not found on the layout. Check if you have more than 1 xml with the same name (for different screen resolutions).